# Missing Drivers from Macbook Installation (A1706) - First Time User

Tags: drivers, macbook-pro

I am unable to connect to wifi, play sound, and a number of other issues.. I feel there are some drivers missing. I am a first-time user.. Please provide some instructions/solutions for this.

Comment: Please ask a separate question about each issue with maximum detail.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps helped me add wireless and video drivers to my iMAC early 2009, I'm assuming you are able to connect to the internet using wired connection.

Click on Show Applications > Additional Drivers > In the Additional Drivers tab look for any proprietary drivers to be installed.  Disconnect the wired connection and I would suggest rebooting after installation, you may then scan for wireless access points.

If Additional Drivers is not installed then in Ubuntu Desktop > Settings (upper right corner) > Applications > Additional Drivers > "Open in Software" button > Install